# C++ constructors take member initializers

Tags: c++

I want to access constructors member initializes as many required. When class object is initialized by program, the default constructor will be called. so at same time, the constructor call constructor initialize what I mentioned.

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    void fun1();
    void fun2();
};
A::A()
    : fun1()
    , fun2()
{
    cout << " Hi" << endl;
}
void A::fun1()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
void A::fun2()
{
    cout << "Bye" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    A obj_a;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected result:

> Hi, Hello, Bye

**Error message**

```
error: class ‘A’ does not have any field named ‘fun1’
A::A():fun1(), fun2() {
```

Comment: A doesn't _have_ data members called `fun1` or `fun2` - it has methods (or member functions) with those names. You don't "initialize" a function, you just call it. Calling a function is not initializing a data member, and again, A doesn't have any of those to initialize. Is this code really an accurate representation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You're trying to initialise _functions_. Why do you think you need that, and what do you want it to do? Explain your requirement in more detail.

Comment: The elements in an initialiser list may look a lot like function calls, but they're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling functions in initializer list, you supposed to initialize data members there. Compiler looks for data member called fun1 and fun2 and cant find any, so you are informed about.
Yo can try like this below:

```
 class A { 
    public: 
    A(); 
    void fun1(); 
    void fun2(); 
  }; 
  A::A() { 
    cout << " Hi" << endl; 
    fun1();
    fun2();
  } 
  void A::fun1() { 
    cout << "Hello" << endl; 
  }       
  void A::fun2() { 
    cout << "Bye" << endl; 
  } 
  int main() { 
    A obj_a; 
    return 0; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error:

```
error: class ‘A’ does not have any field named ‘fun1’
A::A():fun1(), fun2() {
```

Because `class A` does not have any data member with name fun1 or fun2.

Member Initialization List is used to initialize data members or invoking base constructors.

Please see for details: [Constructor & Member Initilization List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Methods of the class can be called within constructor body like:

```
A::A() 
{ 
   fun1();
   fun2();
}
```

Comment: #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class A
    {
    public:
    A();

    private:
    int fun1;
    int  fun2;
    };
    A::A():fun1(12), fun2(14) {
    cout << " Hi"<< endl;
    cout << fun1 <<"\n" << endl;
    cout << fun2 << "\n" << endl;
    }
int main()
{
A obj_a;
return 0;
}